# why won't deepnote display my correct plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, deepnote

[image]

so i guess deepnote says that the code is correct with that green check at the bottom yet still it won't show my plot. Why is that?
It might be important to mention that I'm working with a pretty big file, it has 1000 rows and 15 columns

Comment: do add this on your notebook. `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: thanks- I did that but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Hi @avocami, it would be easier to help you if you shared all of your code you used in Deepnote, or the whole project even better (if possible). And mainly, not in an image, but a code that one could copy, and try to get to the bottom of the problem.